# How to edit footer part in magento framework?

Tags: magento

I am new in magento.I want to change footer part.
**my footer file path**: D:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\footer.phtml.

```
<div class="footer-container">
<div class="footer">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
    <p class="bugs"><?php echo $this->__('Help Us to Keep Magento Healthy') ?> - <a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking" onclick="this.target='_blank'"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Report All Bugs') ?></strong></a> <?php echo $this->__('(ver. %s)', Mage::getVersion()) ?></p>
    <address><?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?></address>
</div>
```

Now I want to remove Help us to keep sentence.

please tell me how to remove this

I have deleted fulll then also it is shown in frontend.

Comment: Are you sure you are at right file path? or are you using different theme? enable template file path hint and check for right file and last clear your cache.

Answer (score 4):

Go to admin section System>Configuration>Advanced>Developer>Debug Then enable Template path hints. After this refresh your site frontend.

You will get the correct information from which theme your file is being loaded.

Then change the correct footer.phtml file.

This message will go.
I think you are new to magento.

For better knowledge read  [Design Packages](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/design/package.html?Highlight=theme%20hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

This is a cache issue.

Navigate to your site's cache:

```
public_html/var/cache //Or where ever the route of your Magento cart is.
```

Then **Delete all the things** in the var directory!

Refresh your site and your changes should appear.